# JavaScript array of objects contains every element of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects (array1).
I want to filter every element, that includes ALL of the tags ([1, 2, 3).
So the result should be id 1. But i cannot make it work. The results i get are id 1, 2 ,4 and i do not understand why exactly it acts like this.

```
let array1 = [
  { id: 1, tags: [1, 2, 3] },
  { id: 2, tags: [2, 3] },
  { id: 3, tags: [0, 3] },
  { id: 4, tags: [1, 3] }
];

let tags = [1, 2, 3];

let includesAll = array1.filter((a1) =>
  a1.tags.every((tag) => tags.includes(tag))
);

console.log(includesAll);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do the opposite. Instead of verifying that every value in `a1.tags` is also in `tags`, you'll want to verify that every value in `tags` is also in `a1.tags`:

```
let includesAll = array1.filter((a1) =>
  tags.every((tag) => a1.tags.includes(tag))
);
```

```js
let array1 = [
  { id: 1, tags: [1, 2, 3] },
  { id: 2, tags: [2, 3] },
  { id: 3, tags: [0, 3] },
  { id: 4, tags: [1, 3] }
];

let tags = [1, 2, 3];

let includesAll = array1.filter((a1) =>
  tags.every((tag) => a1.tags.includes(tag))
);

console.log(includesAll);
```